# Install lacked package but still can not find it when installing SciPy

Tags: scipy

I got the error message below when I install SciPy in the virtual machine with Ubuntu 14. These error message shows that I lack `LAPACK` package so I install `LAPACK` and `BLAS`. I have checked the successful installation of both package but it still shows the same error. I am confused about this and need some help.

```
  Installing collected packages: scipy
      Running setup.py install for scipy

        Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
        with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

          - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                   release)
          - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


        lapack_opt_info:
        openblas_lapack_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['/home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_mkl_info:
        mkl_info:
          libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
          NOT AVAILABLE

          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/shuyu-lyu/venv/lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
        numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
        customize Gnu95FCompiler
        Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
        customize Gnu95FCompiler
        customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
        compiling '_configtest.c':

        /* This file is generated from numpy/distutils/system_info.py */
        void ATL_buildinfo(void);
        int main(void) {
          ATL_buildinfo();
          return 0;
        }

        C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC
```

Comment: well... maybe show what exactly you installed and how... And for people not that familiar with complex source-builds: use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: @sascha Hi, I run command to install all the file in a requirement.txt file. Will installing anaconda can solve the problem? If not, what kind of information you need to help me out of the mess? Thank you very much